# why my asyncstorage do not sync immediately

Tags: react-native, async-await, asyncstorage

i want to have an immediate respond from asyncstorage when i set data
but i cant seem to find a way
here is my code

my listitem onpress => onLearnMore

```
onLearnMore = (rowData) => {
    this.setState({name:rowData.name}),
    this.setState({email:rowData.email}),
    this.setState({phone:rowData.phone}),
    this.setState({street:rowData.location.street}),
    this.setState({city:rowData.location.city}),
    this.setState({state:rowData.location.state}),
    this.setState({postcode:rowData.location.postcode}),
    this.saveData();
    //this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', { ...rowData });
  };
```

saveData to set item to asyncstorage

```
saveData(){
    let data = {
      name: this.state.name,
      email: this.state.email,
      phone: this.state.phone,
      street: this.state.street,
      city: this.state.city,
      state: this.state.state,
      postcode: this.state.postcode,
    }
    AsyncStorage.setItem('data',JSON.stringify(data));
    this.previewData();
  }
```

this is my previewData

```
  previewData = async () =>{
    try{
      let datachecker = await AsyncStorage.getItem('data');
      let parsed = JSON.parse(datachecker);
      alert(parsed.name);
    }catch(error){
      alert(error);
    }
  }
```

but the alert that show the item setted to asyncstorage do not sync immediately. i need to preview it twice to have the same result as setted state properties

update error case
i figure out that when you set data to save into asyncstorage it can sync immediately, is there anyway to fix it?

i am sorry for broken english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState is asynchronous in your first method onLearnMore you should batch all your update to one single setState and pass a callback to the second argument.

```
onLearnMore = (rowData) => {
    this.setState({
      name: rowData.name,
      email: rowData.email,
      phone: rowData.phone,
      street: rowData.location.street,
      city: rowData.location.city,
      state: rowData.location.state,
      postcode: rowData.location.postcode
    }, () => {
     // setState second argument is a callback to be invoked
     // after updating state finished
     // this time you can now call any function that depends on the updated state
       this.saveData();
      //this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', { ...rowData })
    });

  };
```

In your saveData function AsyncStorage.setItem is also asynchronous and returns a promise you could simply use .then or await but if you use await make sure to change the saveData function to async.

using .then

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('data',JSON.stringify(data)).then(this.previewData());
```

or using await

```
async saveData(){
    // omitted code
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('data',JSON.stringify(data));
    this.previewData();
  }
```

Comment: @SirKoswara glad to help

Answer (score 0):

As the name itself suggest, it stores asynchronously. In order to do some operation on completion of `setItem`, a callback function can be passed.
Check http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.49/docs/asyncstorage.html#setitem

Your code needs to be

`AsyncStorage.setItem('data',JSON.stringify(data), this.previewData.bind(this));`

Comment: it stay the same i dont get the immediate saved data
i must click it once more
it's like it is one step behind

Comment: for more information
when i click on other list and save the data
the async become null
is it i need to merge it?